# how to show js errors in multi language. languages are dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a multilingual supporting website.

The languages(English, French, Hindi, etc.) are added dynamically. The php side is OK for multilingual. Its taking from the table. But im using `jquery` for validation.

My problem is how can i show the errors in .js files with that selected languages.

In php its possible by pre defining them all in tables. and fetching them from table based on selected languages.. but in js? I searched they are saying about keeping separate js files for languages.

Comment: I'd add a script tag for a php file that builds a javascript file, based on the language.  For example `<script type="text/javscript" src="script-resources.php"></script>`  That php file could just set a load of string values, taken from your table, and you use those variables in your script rather than hard-coding any messages.

Comment: This should be an answer and not a comment. Very nice thinking.